# Can i set a default value on a picklist based on recordtype

Tags: administration

I am trying to see if can set up picklist default values based on record types?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: If you goto to recordType below select any one of the field there you can see a default option https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hl30AAA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can add a default picklist value based on RecordType**

Goto recordType --> select any one of RecordType

You can see list of all picklist fields.

[image]

Now click on edit link next to field

[image]

You can select default picklist here